# stomp+activemq+perl+cannot sysread(): EOF

Tags: perl, activemq-classic, stomp

I have a simple stomp script to connect to a activemq and when i run the script i get the below error
"cannot sysread(): EOF"

Perl Script Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::STOMP::Client;
$stomp = Net::STOMP::Client->new(uri => "stomp://hostname:61616");
$peer = $stomp->peer();
printf("connected to broker %s (IP %s), port %d\n",
$peer->host(), $peer->addr(), $peer->port());
$stomp->connect();
printf("speaking STOMP %s with server %s\n",
$stomp->version(), $stomp->server() || "UNKNOWN");
printf("session %s started\n", $stomp->session());
$stomp->disconnect();
printf("session ended\n");
```

Could someone please let me know what am I doing wrong ? I saw a similar post but then I didnt see an response regarding the same.
Issue is at $stomp->connect();

Comment: Aren't you supposed to connect first and then check the peer details?

Comment: In your script, I notice your port number 61616 is a TCP port, not STOMP port. Try the port number 61613 instead. To be 100% sure, look in <ActiveMq_HOME>/conf/activemq.xml's <transportConnector name="stomp"....> for the correct port number to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

Debug will help you

```
use Net::STOMP::Client;
$stomp = Net::STOMP::Client->new(
                                uri => "stomp://hostname:61616",
                                debug => "connection api"
                                );
```

Comment: It still gives me the same output as mentioned below::

Comment: connected to broker hostname (IP hostip), port 61616
cannot sysread(): EOF

Comment: Are you sure:
1 STOMP server is listening?

Comment: Are you sure:
1. STOMP server is listening?
try to telnet to this host
telnet> open hostname 61613
2. Are you sure it's STOMP, not MQM?
In this case you need different module MQSeries